# Installing language pack (MUI) on remote desktop services windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, rds

I'm experimenting with the remote desktop services role (terminal server) on server 2008 and I'm not entirely sure if the installation of a language pack should be done in "install mode".

Is it a "best practice" to use "install mode" for **ALL** installations once the RDS role is active or should I be selective depending on what is installed, e.g. language pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that installs that makes changes to the HKCU registry hive on a TS/RDS server also gets written to what is called a shadow key, but only when the server is in install mode. Those settings/keys are then applied to all users that log on to the TS/RDS server.

It's best practice to install ALL software in install mode.

Have a read here:

http://www.brianmadden.com/blogs/brianmadden/archive/2004/07/29/the-windows-registry-in-terminal-server-environments-part-1-of-3.aspx

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: is this still true for Windows Server 2012 R2, i.e. that all software should be installed after changing to install mode?