# Remote Desktop Services install/ execute modes

Tags: windows-server-2012, rds

According to the answer to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/420375/installing-language-pack-mui-on-remote-desktop-services-windows-server-2008) question, everything installed after enabling the Remote Desktop Services role should be done after changing to **install mode.**

I can't find any detailed information on the install/ execute modes and I would like to know if the install/ execute cycle should be done once per installed software or can be done for many simultaneous installations.

For instance,

1) Install mode -> install adobe reader -> execute mode

2) Install mode -> install adobe reader, office, etc -> execute mode

Which one of the above methods is correct or are they both acceptable?

Also, what about software updates within applications. Some software has in-app update mechanisms such as Adobe Reader.

Do I change to install mode before applying those types of updates?

P.S. Are Windows updates exempt from the requirement to switch to install mode?

Comment: `Also, what about software updates within applications. Some software has in-app update mechanisms such as Adobe Reader.` you should be disabling these auto-updates and controlling when and how updates to these applications are deployed - not just in RDP, but across your enterprise.

Comment: Ok but when I want to update those in-app updates I'd login as the admin, launch the application and just update or switch to install mode first?

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with Joe's answer you linked to in part where he states:

> It's best practice to install ALL software in install mode.

Maybe that is best practice, I don't know for certain, but...for "remote administration" installs, where I'm installing applications that are specific for the server itself on a Terminal Server, such as a server A/V endpoint app, or a piece of software I want to run on the server for administrative purposes only, I won't bother to switch to `install mode`.

To me, Install mode is just like Joe pointed out and is also discussed [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/100836/how-to-correctly-install-applications-on-a-remote-desktop-server/), it's for installing an application that will be in use by multiple users at the same time and therefore needs user specific settings/info/ini.

So in your question, I think both #1 and #2 are acceptable...

Comment: If you install say the SCEP client without install mode, does that mean that when users receive files via email etc they are not scanned for viruses/ malware?

Comment: SCEP?  Symantec Endpoint?  http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH91070&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1391625568957 -- might help, but I don't know about email scanning.  Personally I don't use A/V for email scanning at the "client" but rather on the mail servers themselves.  Not that it's wrong...